# Export prop types as TypeScript types in published JavaScript React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component authored in JavaScript and published to an npm repository. This component uses the `prop-types` library to do runtime type checking.

Some of the consumers of this component use TypeScript, and would like type definitions for the component and its props. I'm willing to add an `index.d.ts` file to my project with type declarations, but since the component already declares the accepted types for the props with `prop-types`, I'd like to re-use those and not have to maintain types in two different source files.

I know that `@types/prop-types` adds a utility type, `InferProps`, that can convert a propTypes object into a usable TypeScript type. But when I attempt to use that within my `index.d.ts` file, the imported propTypes object is typed as `any`!

#### src/MyComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyComponent ({color, quantity}) => <p>Color was {color}, quantity: {quantity}</p>;

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string,
  quantity: PropTypes.number
};

export default MyComponent;
```

#### @types/index.d.ts

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MyComponent from '../src';


declare const MyComponentType: React.FC<
  PropTypes.InferProps<
    typeof MyComponent.propTypes
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this always seems to resolve to `any`
  >
>;

export default MyComponentType;
```

Is it possible to import JavaScript code in a TypeScript declaration file? What am I missing?

Comment: For what it's worth, everything seems to work as you except in pure typescript land: https://tsplay.dev/oN59oN

Comment: Yep, that’s what I observed as well. Just (I think) not when used in a declaration file.

Comment: It looks like if I copy the non-TS source file somewhere and change the extension to `.ts` then the import is no longer `any` and `InferProps` works correctly, but of course then `tsc` can see it and throws a ton of errors since it isn't actually valid TS.